# y''+y=cos(t) what is the smallest possible value of t for which |y(t)|>10?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Not sure if this is correct, but I was able to find a general solution of the form:
y= c1cos(t)+c2sin(t)+(1/2)tsin(t)
I'm not sure how I would go about finding the smallest possible value to make the statement true. y(t)=10 when t is approximately 25.96 so would the answer be 25.96+infinitesimal value.

Comment: How do you get $y(t)=10$ when $t\approx 25.96$ without choosing particular values for $c_1$ and $c_2$ first?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit about how you tried to solve it, and add more context to your question. And if possible format the expressions with Mathjax to make it more legible, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: Forgot to choose c1 and c2 my bad. c1=0 and c2=1/2

Comment: It looks to me like you missed a lot of smaller positive solutions.  You should review how you got 25.96 in light of the graphs I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting your solution $y=c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t)+\frac 12t\sin(t)$ we can have $t$ as small as we want.  Just choose $c_1 \gt 10$ and any $t$ that is a negative multiple of $2\pi$.  Then $\cos(t)=1$ and $\sin(t)=0$  You need some initial conditions that force $c_1,c_2$ to make this a reasonable problem.

Added:  if $c_1=0, c_2 = \frac 12$ if you just ask [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201%2F2sin%28t%29%2Bt*sin%28t%29) to plot it you can see that large values of $|y|$ extend to $-\infty$ so there is no answer to your question.

Added2: presumably you are requiring that $t \gt 0$.  **Please** get the question right.  From the Alpha page I linked to before the minimum $t$ comes when $y=-10$. [Zooming in](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201%2F2sin%28t%29%2Bt*sin%28t%29from%2010%20to%2015) shows it near $t=10.6$  Now you can use your favorite root finder to get closer.

Comment: c_1=0 and c_2= \frac 12, sorry forgot to include that.

Comment: If we assumed that only positive values of t are accepted then how would you state a smallest possible t that makes the statement valid. Could it be that my solution to the problem is incorrect? The initial conditions are y(0)=0 and y'(0)=1/2.

Comment: You didn't say that $t \ge 0$, so I didn't assume it at first.  That was my point about getting the question right.  You had constants that you didn't supply and a constraint that you didn't supply.

Comment: sorry should have stated, but I wasn't sure that was an actual constraint applied to the original problem as it was presented to me.

Comment: [This plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2F2sin%28t%29%2Bt*sin%28t%29from+10+to+11) shows it is close to $10.6$.  You won't find an algebraic solution, so rootfind.  [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+1%2F2sin%28t%29%2Bt*sin%28t%29%3D-10+near+t%3D10.6) shows $t \approx 10.55512$